# jQuery validate phone number with with RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have a simple ajax form and I'm trying to validate that it

1. has a value
2. that value is a 10 digit number

I'm trying to use RegEx to do so. Here is what I have so far.

```
var reg = new RegExp("/[0-9]{10}/");
$("#call_form").bind("submit", function() {
       if ($("#call_number").val().length < 1 && reg.test($("#call_number").val())) {
               $("#call_error").show();
                return false;
        }
});
```

I know the problem has to do witht he RegExp as if I remove this portion of the code it validates that the box has a value.

**EDIT**: Here is the final regex I'm using

```
var regEx = new RegExp("/[0-9]/");

$("#call_form").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#call_number").val().length != 10 && !$("#call_number").val().match(regEx)) {
        $("#call_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**
Using the suggestions here is what i'm usign which allows spaces and dashes that then get stripped on check

```
    $("#call_form").bind("submit", function() {
var Phone = $("#call_number").val().replace(/\D+/g,'');

if (Phone.length != 10) {
        $("#call_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: That regex will only check to see if there's at least one number in the string.  You should keep the `{10}` to ensure that it's all numbers.

Comment: @tjameson Ok, If I keep the `{10}` I should be able to ditch the `length != 10` right? or is it better not to?

Comment: Yeah, but you should have both.  reg.test will return true if the regexp matches any part of the string.

Comment: Or you could anchor your RegExp using ^ and $: `/^[0-9]{10}$/` I think is the syntax.

Comment: @tjameson I know that's the PHP syntax I'll give it a go in JS

Comment: for some reason anchors arn't working :-/

Comment: I'd like to also point out that you seem to be ignoring the fact that people LOVE to put `(555)555-5555` etc into phone number fields, I personally use `555.555.5555` all the time when typing my number into forms and hate it when some poorly written regexp denies me... I would suggest not validating the field at all, especially when you must consider `+44 02 5555 5555` as well...  You could also just `.replace(/\D+/g,'')` on the string to remove all non-numbers then check `.length >= 10` to ensure at least 10 numbers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex works fine for me... you could shorten it to just `/[0-9]{10}/`.

Your problem is here:

`$("#call_number").val().length < 1`.  If the number is 10 characters long, it will never be less than 1, no?

You probably meant something like this:

`$("#call_number").val().length === 10`

Comment: So true, I went with a combination of both answers.

Comment: Should be `/^\d{10}$/` -- need the anchors if you want to ensure nothing else, otherwise 11 numbers would pass, and so would 12 letters, 10 numbers, then some symbols

Comment: Yeah, the \d is simpler.  In the comments to the question I gave him the anchors.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I use - its simple, just posting if someone is searching for the same.

```
var a = PHONE_FROM_FIELD;
var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
if (filter.test(a)) {
     return true;
}
else {
     return false;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

No one has said what was wrong with your original effort - it's the slashes (/). When calling *RegExp* as a constructor, you don't need the slashes (which are a token to indicate a regular expression litteral), e.g.:

```
var re = /\w+/i;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\w+','i');
```

Note that you have to quote backslashes for special characters.

One last thing - allow spaces in the number. You might remove them before testing or storing though. Users find it much easier to read numbers in blocks of 3 or 4 digits, e.g.

- 1234 871 098 is easier to read than 1234871098.

Comment: Nice catch! I totally just read over it without flagging it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var regEx = /^(\+\d)*\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$/;
$("#call_form").bind("submit", function() {
       var val = $("#call_number").val();
       if (!val.match(regEx)) {
            $("#call_error").show();
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: This regex is more complete and will parse the dashes it looks like.  Watch out though, match returns an array of matches.

Comment: I edited the question to include the solution. I went with simple regex just means no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate_Phone_Number() {
    var number = $('field_Id').val();
    var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
    if (filter.test(number)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use same validation with keypress and keyup using jquery , working for me

**jquery code**

```
    const goodColor = "#0C6";
    const badColor = "#FF0000";

    const $mobile_validation = $('#mobile_validation');
    
$('#mobile').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 46 || e.which == 45 || e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
    
                if(this.value.length !=10 ){
                    $mobile_validation.text("Please enter 10 digit mobile number ");
                    $mobile_validation.css("color", badColor);
                }
    
                if(this.value.length ===10 ){
                    $mobile_validation.text("Good!");
                    $mobile_validation.css("color", goodColor);
                }
            });
```

**html code**

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control" name="telephone" maxlength="10">
<span id="mobile_validation"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// check phone number validation
        function validatePhoneNumber(number)
        {
            count=number.length;
            if(number[0]!=" " && number[0]!="-" && number[count-1]!=" " && number[count-1]!="-")
            {
                temp=number.replace(" ", "");
                temp=temp.replace("-", "");
                if($.isNumeric(temp))
                {
                    if(temp.length>=7 && temp.length<=12)
                    {
                        flag=1;
                        for(i=1;i<count;i++)
                        {           
                            if(number[i]=="-" || number[i]==" ")
                            {
                                if(number[i-1]=="-" || number[i-1]==" " || number[i+1]=="-" || number[i+1]==" ")
                                {
                                    flag=0;
                                }
                            }               
                        }

                        if(flag==1)
                        {
                            valid=1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            valid=0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valid=0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    valid=0;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                valid=0;
            }
            return valid;
        }
```