# Valid data in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery validate phone number with with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692232/jquery-validate-phone-number-with-with-regex)

we have to allow only 10 digits in a text field along with , . ( ) - also.
(US phone number format.) It should not allow 11 th digit when i am entering data in this text field.If i delete all the data it will again allow me to enter upto 10 digits.
this field is also using to enter email to login.
For Email and mobile number same text field.
Please help me out to do it.

Comment: You have your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692232/jquery-validate-phone-number-with-with-regex

Happy coding!!

Comment: try checking the input in textbox in textbox change event. If it has @ sign, then allow other wise restrict it to 10 digit length. you can use the following code. $('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use **maxlength** attribute on html input element. something like :

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10" />
```

You can also use regular expressions for email and US phone number format in same input element by using IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to validate the input.

```
$(function () {
            $('#yourtextboxid').change(function () {
                //call a function that will check for @ sign into the text. If @ exists, //then allow user's input alse restrict it to 10 digit length.
            });
        });
```

You can check the length as

```
$("#call_number").val().length === 10
```